# How to check that a string is among a fixed set of values in rust?

Tags: string, rust

I want to check if the value of a string is among a fixed set of values. I tried the following (`s` is a `String`):

```rust
["foo", "bar", "baz"].contains(&*s)
```

The compiler says that the argument to `contains` is invalid:

```
    = note: expected reference `&&str`
                found reference `&std::string::String`
```

I even tried `&&*s` instead of `&*s`, but it still doesn't work. I don't understand why the compiler thinks it's still a `String` when I dereferenced it using `*s`, which should give a `str`.

Comment: `s` is not `String`. That would look like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ddbc2ec5686b362610f8e8593aeaef4c). `s` is `&String`, which you can [dereference twice](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=156453f83b475ac17f5da97694cabb99).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the array has elements of type `&str`, the `.contains()` method expects a `&&str` parameter (`&T` with `T` being `&str`).

A `String` has a `.as_str()` method providing a `&str` on its content.
Then `[...].contains(&s.as_str())` is at the same time not too long to write but still explicit (not a convoluted combination of `&*...`).

Answer (score -2):

Check out:
'slice::contains'
https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.contains

'str::contains`
https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.contains

This example should help:

```
fn main() {
    let a: [&str; 3] = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
    let s: &str = "foo";
    let s2 = String::from("bar");
    
    assert!(a.contains(&s));
    assert!(a.contains(&&*s2));

    // This will error: 
    assert!(a.contains(&*s2)); // error expected `&&str`, found `&str`
    assert!(a.contains(*s2)); // error expected `&&str`, found `String`
    assert!(a.contains(s2)); // error: expected `&&str`, found `String`

    assert!(a.contains(s)); // error: ^ expected `&&str`, found `&str`

    let b = "banana";
    assert!(b.contains("nana")); // will pass; str::contains

    


}
```